# Не получается создать указатели в многомерном массиве

Tags: c++, c

Есть задание:Написать программу для обработки данных, организованных в массив, согласно задача приведенного варианта. В программах использовать различные формы обращения к элементам многомерных массивов, в том числе с помощью конструкций ***"указатель на массив"*** и ***"указатель на указатель"***. Учитывать, что каждая строка матрицы можно обрабатывать как отдельный элемент.
*Ввести прямоугольную матрицу целых чисел. Напечатать номера строк матрицы, все элементы которых нечетные (или вывести сообщение об отсутствии таких строк). Переставить элементы всех остальных строк в обратном порядке.*

***Для выполнения полного задания сделал все кроме одного:*** создать указатель на елемент многомерного массива, и использовать его.

Весь код програмы:

`DEFINE ROWS 3
 DEFINE COLS 4`

```
int main()
{
int iMatrix[ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &iMatrix[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\n");

int status = 0;
int Odds = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        if (iMatrix[i][j]%2==1)
        {
            status = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (status == 1)
    {
        printf("[%d] Row have all odd elements\t\t\t\t\t   ", i + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", iMatrix[i][j]);
            Odds++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[%d] Row which have all pair elements written at inverse direction: ", i+1);
            for (int j = COLS-1; j >=0 ;j--)
            {
                printf("%d\t", iMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            continue;
    }

}

if (Odds == 0)
    printf("There aren't rows with all odd elements.\n");


printf("\nYour input:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", iMatrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

***После кода пытался создать указатель на массив, выдает ошибки***

*В чем может быть ошибка?*

```
int memory = sizeof(iMatrix) / sizeof(int);

int* ptr;
for (ptr = (int*)iMatrix; ptr < (int*)iMatrix + memory; ptr++)
{
    scanf("%d", (int*)iMatrix);
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое "после кода"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
    /* ptr - указатель на массив: */
    int *ptr = iMatrix[i];
    for( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
        printf( "%d ", *( ptr + j ) );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```